# Testing issues with MVC Controller using IOC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am testing my controller code using IOC Unity. The issue is with the initialisation of the model that I am passing to constructor of my controller.

Here is my code in the test project

```
  [TestMethod]
        public void TestHomeControllerIndexMethod()
        {
            HomeController controller = new HomeController(new stubPeopleService());
            ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

            Assert.AreEqual(0, result);
        }
```

Below is the code of the stubPeopleService that I have created which I pass to my controller constructor above

```
  public class stubPeopleService : IPeople
        {

            public int Age
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public string BirthPlace
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public DateTime DateOfBirth
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int GetAge(DateTime reference, DateTime birthday)
            {
                int age = reference.Year - birthday.Year;
                if (reference < birthday.AddYears(age)) age--;

                return age + 1;
            }

            public int Height
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public List<People> listPeople { get { return GetPeople(); } }

            public string Name
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int Weight
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            private List<People> GetPeople()
            {

                List<People> list = new List<People>();
                list.Add(new People
                {
                    Name = "Ranjit Menon",
                    DateOfBirth = DateTime.Today,
                    BirthPlace = "London",
                    Age = 25,
                    Height = 175,
                    Weight = 85
                });


                return list.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
            }

        }
```

When I debug my test , I notice that the all the properties do not contain any value. The only property that contains value is listPeople property. The listpeople property does initialise the other properties but throws an object cannot be created error.Let me know if I am doing the test correctly. I need to do a test initialising the model with some values.

Code from my home controller

```
       private IPeople peopleService;

            public HomeController(IPeople people)
            {
                this.peopleService = people;
            }

 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(peopleService);
        }
```

Please find the IPeople interface below

```
public interface IPeople
    {
        int Age { get; set; }
        string BirthPlace { get; set; }
        DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        int GetAge(DateTime reference, DateTime birthday);
        int Height { get; set; }
        List<People> listPeople { get; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        int Weight { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show some of the HomeController code, the constructor would be nice :)

Comment: Hi @Vasil, I have edited to add the home controller code. Please find the code in my post.

Comment: how does IPeople interface look like?

Comment: Hi @avidenic , I have posted the IPeople interface.

Comment: @user3751248 sorry but I cannot see a problem from the code you posted. Must be something else. 

I've tried to reproduce it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nk35ne